# Return a column once time

Tags: sqlite

I execute a query in my DB:

```
SELECT table1.*, tabl2.* FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING(id);
```

In these 2 tables i have a common column "id". What I have to ask, in order to get the column 'id' once time in the results and not twice?
I thought one solution is to write down in the query which columns I want. But If I want to avoid this (as there are many) ?

Comment: If you don't want * you must tell it what you do want; i.e. by listing them.

Comment: ok I was wondering how I could use `*` to avoid listing all the columns I want

Answer (score 0):

Will it work for you to name specific columns you need from both tables? something like:

```
    SELECT table1.id, table2.other_column1, table2.other_column2 FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING(id);
```

You are selecting all fields from both tables by using (*)